# Usage of integers as hash keys

Tags: ruby, hashmap

Is it appropriate to use integers as keys in a Ruby hash?

Every example from documentation shows a string or symbol being used as a key, but never an integer.

Internally, would integers somehow get converted to strings? I have seen some conflicting information on the subject.

In other words, is there any significant disadvantage to using integer keys to a hash?

Comment: Have you tried it? On your console, you can type IRB and get a ruby console.. pretty useful for trying this type of things...On topic, you should be able to use integers just fine.

Comment: ["except that indexing is done via arbitrary keys of any object type"](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html). Integers are objects in Ruby, so are Hashes for that matter so you could use Hashes as keys.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

of course you can use integers as keys...

```
h = {1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three'}

(1..3).each do |i|
  puts h[i]
end
```

=>

```
one
two
there
```

irb is your friend!  try it..

---

In fact you can use **any Ruby object** as the key (or the value).
We usually don't think about using Hashes like this, but it could be quite useful.

Edit:
As Óscar López points out, the object just has to respond to `.hash` for it to work as a key in a Ruby Hash.

Comment: One thing I find interesting about hash literals with numeric keys is that you cannot use the syntax {1:'one', 2:'two'}. I guess that syntax assumes every key is a symbol, which integers are not.

Comment: this is a peculiarity of the Ruby 1.9 Hash syntax. This is not a general limitation of the Hash class..

Answer (score 85):

Others looking at the answers here might find it interesting to know that an exception happens when you use integers as symbol keys in a [Ruby hash](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_hashes.html) `{symbol: value}`

```
hash = {1: 'one'} # will not work  
hash = {1 => 'one'} # will work
```

**Requested Explanation:**

The simplest answer for why the first example fails is probably that `to_sym` is not a method that's been implemented for [Fixnum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#M001071) integers.

To go more in depth to maybe explaining why that is, one of the main benefits to using symbols is that two symbols are in fact "the same object". Or at least they share the same object ids.

```
:foo.object_id == :foo.object_id
=> true
```

Strings that are the same do not share the same objects, and therefore do not share the same object ids.

```
"foo".object_id == "foo".object_id
=> false
```

Like symbols, Fixnum integers that are the same will have the same object ids. Therefore you don't really need to convert them into symbols.

```
one = 1
=> 1
uno = 1
=> 1
one.object_id
=> 3
one.object_id == uno.object_id
=> true
```

Comment: This is just a peculiarity of the "new" Ruby hash syntax, which uses symbols as keys, and was introduced in Ruby 1.9. It is not a limitation in Ruby's Hash implementation. This syntax is only applicable if you want to have symbols as keys, e.g. `{this: 'one', that: 'two'}`. It is just a subset of what the Hash class supports.

Comment: Ruby is the jankiest language I've ever worked with

Answer (score 9):

The only requirement for using an object as a hash key is that it must respond to the message hash with a hash value, and the hash value for a given key must not change. For instance, if you call this:

```
1.hash()
```

You can see that the number 1 indeed responds to the hash message

Comment: I think it used to be so in 1.8. But I'm not so sure it's still true in 1.9. I mean, in 1.9 you get a hash for free.

Comment: Right, I didn't mean to say that you have to explicitly call hash() on the object you want to use as a key - what matters is that the object implements the hash() method (or 'responds to the hash message', in OO parlance)

Comment: It also has to respond to `eql?`.

Answer (score 3):

There are already answers about the `is it possible?`.

An explanation, why there are no examples with integers as Hash-keys.

Hash-keys have (most of the times) a meaning. It may be an attribute name and its value (e.g. `:color => 'red'`...).

When you have an integer as a key, your semantic may be 'first, second ...' (1). But then you don't use a hash, but an array to store your values.

(1) A counterexample may be a foreign key in a database.